# Как сделать так, чтобы часть картинки было за блоком а часть перед блоком? Так как на картинке желательно

Tags: html, css

На картинке PSD макет. Нужно поставить очки в таком положении как изображено на картинке. html и css

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/edR8G.png]

Comment: Невозможно( Только вставлять как картинку

Comment: Что за позор? Почему тень от дужки падает на рамку, если дужка находится за ней?

Comment: @MaximLensky Это похоже, но это не совсем то что нужно. Но все равно спасибо за помощь.

Comment: если будут три разных детали то можно

Comment: или на svg рисовать очки - тогда точно можно

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант это разбить изображение на основное и фоновое, а затем уже играть с  z-index:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  border: 13px solid #e3e107;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
.glass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: -150px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: move 2s infinite;
}
.back {
  z-index: -1;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: -120px;
  }

  50% {
    left: -180px;
  }
  
  100% {
    left: -120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="glass back" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pggk5.png">
  <img class="glass" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXUAL.png">
</div>
```